# Inserting foreign key into SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

With the tables below, I am trying to answer this question and I have no idea how to answer it:

"Show the sum of HoursWorked for each Type of OWNER but exclude services of employees who have ExperienceLevel of Junior and exclude any Type with less than three members."

```
CREATE TABLE OWNER
(
    OwnerID     Int             NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1)     PRIMARY KEY,
    OwnerName   Char(30)        NOT NULL,
    OwnerEmail  VarChar(100)    NULL,
    OwnerType   Char(15)        NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE PROPERTY
(
    PropertyID      Int         NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)      PRIMARY KEY,
    PropertyName    Char(30)    NOT NULL,   
    Street          Char(20)    NOT NULL,
    City            Char(25)    NOT NULL,
    State           Char(10)    NOT NULL,   
    Zip             Char(5)     NOT NULL,
    OwnerID         Int         NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT  PROP_OWN_FK FOREIGN KEY(OwnerID)
                REFERENCES OWNER(OwnerID),
);

CREATE TABLE GG_EMPLOYEE
(
    EmployeeID      Int         NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)      PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName        Char(35)    NOT NULL,
    FirstName       Char(35)    NOT NULL,
    CellPhone       Char(20)    NOT NULL,
    ExperienceLevel Char(25)    NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE SERVICE 
(
    PropertyID      Int         NOT NULL,
    EmployeeID      Int         NOT NULL,
    ServiceDate     Char(15)    NOT NULL,
    HoursWorked     Char(5)     NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT  SERVICE_PK  PRIMARY KEY(PropertyID, EmployeeID, ServiceDate),
    CONSTRAINT  SER_PRO_FK FOREIGN KEY(PropertyID)
                REFERENCES PROPERTY(PropertyID),                        
    CONSTRAINT  SER_GG_EMP_FK FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeID)
                REFERENCES GG_EMPLOYEE(EmployeeID),
);

INSERT INTO OWNER 
VALUES ('Mary Jones', 'Mary.Jones@somewhere.com', 'Individual');

INSERT INTO OWNER 
VALUES('DT Enterprises', 'DTE@dte.com', 'Corporation');

INSERT INTO OWNER 
VALUES('Sam Douglas', NULL, 'Individual');

INSERT INTO OWNER 
VALUES('UNY Enterprises', 'UNYE@unye.com', 'Corporation');

INSERT INTO OWNER 
VALUES('Doug Samuels', 'Doug.Samuels@somewhere.com', 'Individual');

INSERT INTO PROPERTY 
VALUES('Eastlake Building', '123 Eastlake', 'Seattle', 'WA', '98119');

INSERT INTO PROPERTY 
VALUES('Elm St Apts', '4 East Elm', 'Lynwood', 'WA', '98223');

INSERT INTO PROPERTY 
VALUES('Jefferson Hill', '42 West 7th St', 'Bellevue', 'WA', '98007');

INSERT INTO PROPERTY 
VALUES('Lake View Apts', '1265 32nd Avenue', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98054');

INSERT INTO PROPERTY 
VALUES('Kodak Heights Apts', '65 32nd Avenue', 'Rochester', 'NY', '14604');

INSERT INTO PROPERTY 
VALUES('Private Residence', '1456 48th St', 'Bellevue', 'WA', '98007');

INSERT INTO PROPERTY 
VALUES('Private Residence', '1567 51st St', 'Bellevue', 'WA', '98007');

INSERT INTO PROPERTY 
VALUES('Private Residence', '718 151st St', 'Rochester', 'NY', '14604');

INSERT INTO GG_EMPLOYEE 
VALUES('Smith', 'Sam', '206-254-1234', 'Master');

INSERT INTO GG_EMPLOYEE 
VALUES('Evanston', 'John', '206-254-2345', 'Senior');

INSERT INTO GG_EMPLOYEE 
VALUES('Murray', 'Dale', '206-254-3456', 'Junior');

INSERT INTO GG_EMPLOYEE 
VALUES('Murphy', 'Jerry', '585-545-8765', 'Master');

INSERT INTO GG_EMPLOYEE 
VALUES('Fontaine', 'Joan', '206-254-4567', 'Senior');

INSERT INTO SERVICE VALUES('2015-05-05', '4.50');
INSERT INTO SERVICE VALUES('2015-05-08', '2.75');
INSERT INTO SERVICE VALUES('2015-05-08', '4.50');
INSERT INTO SERVICE VALUES('2015-05-19', '3.00');
INSERT INTO SERVICE VALUES('2015-05-12', '7.50');
INSERT INTO SERVICE VALUES('2015-05-10', '2.50');
INSERT INTO SERVICE VALUES('2015-05-19', '2.50');
INSERT INTO SERVICE VALUES('2015-05-15', '2.75');
```

If someone could please help me, that would be great!

Comment: what / where is the error?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Share the query. That doesn't seem to be a problem. Did you try to get the last inserted id of Owner table?

Comment: when i try to insert data into the PROPERTY and SERVICE table, it says that the number of columns doesn't match the number of data I have in the INSERT statement

Comment: @LukeHarding check the no. of column present in your table and supply the no of values accordingly while writing Insert Statement. i.e you need to provide value of `OwnerID` for Insert statement of PROPERTY & values of 'PropertyID' and 'EmployeeID' for Insert Statement of SERVICE table

Comment: @ManojNaik I was able to get it working, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Columns `OwnerID` in  `Property` Table and `PropertyId` and `EmployeeID` in `Service` table are making trouble for you.

Following are the reason for that.

> 1) All the mentioned columns are set as `NOT NULL`. So these column
>   always expect value for every insert.
>
> 2) Also,In 'service' table ,columns `PropertyId` and `EmployeeID` are
>   part of composite primary key. Primary key doesn't allow `NULL` values.
>
> 3)Once you handle the points 1 and 2,You can make the insert by
>   mentioning   columns in your `INSERT` query,like below

```
INSERT INTO PROPERTY (PropertyName,Street,City,[State],Zip) 
VALUES('Eastlake Building', '123 Eastlake', 'Seattle', 'WA', '98119');

INSERT INTO [SERVICE] (ServiceDate,HoursWorked) 
VALUES('2015-05-05', '4.50');
```

[image]

Comment: You can set NULL constraint for OwnerID in Property table,if you are updating the OwnerId after inserting the data as mentioned in your query.You cannot set NULL value to propertyd and EmployeeID in Service table ,since they are part of primary key. So your insert will fail.

Comment: if you wanted to make inserts as you mentioned,you need to remove the column ( propertyd and EmployeeID) from the primary key constraint and to set column defaults to 'NULL' for all the three columns (OwnerID,PropertyID and EmployeeID).                                             If you wanted to keep all these constraint as such,you need to pass the required values for these columns with the INSERT query itself.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3ea54

You need to say who is the owner, the insert doesnt know that.

here I assing every property to `owner = 1`

```
INSERT INTO PROPERTY VALUES('Eastlake Building', '123 Eastlake', 'Seattle', 'WA', '98119', 1);
INSERT INTO PROPERTY VALUES('Elm St Apts', '4 East Elm', 'Lynwood', 'WA', '98223', 1 );
INSERT INTO PROPERTY VALUES('Jefferson Hill', '42 West 7th St', 'Bellevue', 'WA', '98007', 1);
INSERT INTO PROPERTY VALUES('Lake View Apts', '1265 32nd Avenue', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98054', 1);
INSERT INTO PROPERTY VALUES('Kodak Heights Apts', '65 32nd Avenue', 'Rochester', 'NY', '14604', 1);
INSERT INTO PROPERTY VALUES('Private Residence', '1456 48th St', 'Bellevue', 'WA', '98007', 1);
INSERT INTO PROPERTY VALUES('Private Residence', '1567 51st St', 'Bellevue', 'WA', '98007', 1);
INSERT INTO PROPERTY VALUES('Private Residence', '718 151st St', 'Rochester', 'NY', '14604', 1);
```

Comment: The OwnerID and EmployeeID are supposed to populate themselves which they do; however, for some reason I have to manually enter the PropertyID data in the INSERT statements when I shouldn't have to

Answer (score 0):

hey luke problem is that in insert query values count is not matching with column count of tables.
if u want to use advantage of Auto increment property write insert query with column names.
and column 'OwnerID' in PROPERTY table and 'EmployeeID' in SERVICE table can not be null as you restricted in table creation.